# is it possible to use two background in the same day in the calendar?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, calendar

I have calendar in one of my controls. At the moment, I am be able to change the baackground color of the days with different colors according to some conditions. It is done in a converter.

I am using MVVM pattern.

But now I have a new condition, so some days must be branded, but keeping the color. So I don't know how to do that.

I try to use the property BlackOutDays, but the cross is very tenous and this does not allow to select the day, and I need to select the day.

Soy How could I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: how should that work? How would two backgrounds be displayed? If you mean "half one and half another", for example, make a new background and assign it to that.

Comment: What do you mean by "the cross is very tenous" exactly?

Comment: I mean with tenous that is very hard to see if a day is blackoutday or not. I would like a stronger color.

Comment: well if all your looking for is a differentiating factor why are you just sticking to `Background`? try modifying the `Foreground`, `BorderBrush` or a different property to set them apart than try to blend multiple colors or half n half them.